# How to push require view controller to navigation controller in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing a application which has login screen and verify code screen. Once user logged in,and logout I need to show only login screen so how can I manage the navigation view controller. Right now, my verifycode view controller is coming first before showing the login view controller when I am pressing the sign out button.

Could you please let me know how can I manage the view controller?

Comment: what you want to ? add exact flow here

Comment: LoginViewController -->VerifycodeViewController- > MainViewController ->LoginViewController

Comment: you need to pop back to loginViewController from MainViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (`AppDelegate`):

```
    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    if (User.isLogged) {
        window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC") as! LoginVC
    } else {
        window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!
    }

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Create class `User` when you can storage information about status user (Authorized or not) and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` check this status and set rootViewController for window.